# ReactJS Error: true is not a PostCSS plugin

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, node-modules, postcss

I'm getting this error out of nowhere.
The reason I'm making this is because I read through different posts and questions, but the thing is I never manually installed any postcss stuff, so I'm not sure how to approach this.

Here's my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "author": "me",
  "description": "Description",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron": "^19.0.10",
    "electron-compile": "^6.4.4",
    "electron-forge": "^5.2.4",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "fuzzysort": "^2.0.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dropdown": "^1.10.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.15.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "reactjs-popup": "^2.0.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dev": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm start\" \"npm:electron\"",
    "electron": "wait-on tcp:3000 && electron .",
    "package": "react-scripts build && electron-forge package",
    "make-mac": "react-scripts build && electron-forge make --platform darwin",
    "make-linux": "react-scripts build && electron-forge make --platform linux",
    "make": "react-scripts build && electron-forge make"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^7.3.0",
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "8.2.0",
    "wait-on": "^6.0.1"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  },
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "stock_trading_app"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin",
            "linux",
            "win32"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The error comes from both `npm run start` and `npm run build`. I haven't touched the `electron` stuff for a long time and 1) I don't need it as of now anymore and 2) I'm pretty sure Electron is not the issue in this case.

I have 8 `css` files and every file is giving me the same error, that is:

```
ERROR in ./src/utils/Button.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/utils/Button.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: true is not a PostCSS plugin
    at Processor.normalize (C:\Users\...\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:145:15)
    at new Processor (C:\Users\...\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:51:25)
    at postcss (C:\Users\...\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js:73:10) 
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\...\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js:96:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:437:9)
```

I started having this error after running `npm update`, but I don't know what updates caused it to crash like this.

Comment: Do you have a `postcss.config.js` file or similar?

Comment: @SteffenAndreasKloster Nope...just a package.json and a package-lock.json